# Shell Scripting - less than operation not working

Tags: shell

```
echo "Enter age"
read $ag

if [[ $ag -lt 30 ]]

then
echo "Age is less than 30"

else
echo "not"

fi
```

For this program, whatever be the value of 'ag', the output is shown as "Age is less than 30".
What could be reason? and a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is:

```
read $ag
```

You should write:

```
read ag
```

With your current syntax, `read` stores the user input in a variable whose name is the content of variable `ag`.

Answer (score 0):

An `echo $ag` after the `read` would have told you. (Checking your input and your assumptions is elementary debugging, really.)

```
read $ag
```

This resolves `$ag` (which is undefined), giving:

```
read
```

You're reading, but you're not reading *into* the variable as you expected. `$ag` is still empty, which resolves to "less than 30".

Fix:

```
read ag
```

That's the proper syntax for `read`.